# BorderLayout.CENTER equivalent in SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, swt

Which layout just stretches/shrinks one single control to the entire size of parent control in SWT?

Like BorderLayout.CENTER does in AWT?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FillLayout or GridLayout (with GridData being set to grab excess horizontal and vertical space).

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/FillLayout.html

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridLayout.html